# /usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lCUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND

Tags: cuda, make, gpu, cmake, caffe

I get the following error while installing a GPU pytorch library. `cmake ..` has been compiled correctly but l do `make -j4` l get the following error

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/operators/rnn/recurrent_network_executor_gpu.cc.o    
[ 98%] Building CXX object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/queue/queue_ops_gpu.cc.o                             
[ 98%] Building CXX object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/iter_op_gpu.cc.o                                 
[ 98%] Building CXX object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/learning_rate_op_gpu.cc.o                        
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libcaffe2_gpu.so                                                        
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lCUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND                                              
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/build.make:4511: lib/libcaffe2_gpu.so] Error 1                    
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1925: caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/all] Error 2                           
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error
```

What is wrong ?
such that CUDA,CUDNN, nvidia-smi, Gpu pytorch have been installed.
I'm working on  conda environment

Comment: How are you trying to specify the library in your makefile?  -lcublas_device would be the expected way, with the CUDA library location specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when using LibTorch. What solved it for me was **upgrading to CMake=3.15.2**. I found this solution here: https://github.com/clab/dynet/issues/1457. They say version 3.12.2 is sufficient.

**In case your using Ubuntu >=18.04**, 3.10.2 is the latest cmake version provided by apt. You can install a more recent version via snap:

```
sudo apt purge cmake # Remove cmake.
sudo snap install cmake --classic # Install a more recent. Note: it requires to disable security confinement.
```

You will find the executable in `/snap/bin/cmake`, so you might have to append run

```
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/snap/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

and reopen your Terminal. Now `cmake --version` should give you a more recent one.